# getSignature using Docusign SDK

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

Hi I would like to ask do we have a way to get only the signature after we sign and submit the envelope? correct me but I've found this API `/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/signatures/{signatureId}`.

Is it the right API?

- if it is what should I call in the Docusign SDK?
- How do I define the signatureId in my application?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** if you need a signer image for a specific envelope/recipient you can use this https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/getrecipientsignatureimage/

```
envelopesApi.getRecipientSignature(accountId, envelopeID, recipientId);
```

This endpoint of the eSignature REST API is specific to a user in the account. It is not related to an envelope or a document that was signed.

Users can adopt their signature that they can use every time they sign. This is what this endpoint does.

User may have more than one signature, so you need to also provide the signatureId you want.

To get all the signatures for a given user, use `listSignatures(accountId, userId)` and that will give you a list that includes the signatureId for each signature.

You can use it from the node.js SDK like this:

```
let dsApiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();
dsApiClient.setBasePath(basePath);
dsApiClient.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);    let usersApi = new docusign.UsersApi(dsApiClient);
usersApi.getSignature(accountId, userId, signatureId); // need to provide accountId, userId and signatureId
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the signature from an envelope or using an envelopeId? Because right now I'm using JWT token, which means all users that signed used the same impersonatedUser right? So I can't get the signature from one specified user.

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/getrecipientsignatureimage/